# One-liner efficient Gnu/Linux command to check the CPU, RAM and the Hard Disk usage percentage?

Tags: linux, python

I want an **efficient** Gnu/Linux one-liner command(or multiple commands clubbed together) to check the **current** percentage of usage of CPU, RAM, and the Hard Disk.

Note : I'm using python [pexpect/pxssh](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/ssh-connection-with-python) and running a script in crontab hourly. The script performs the ssh and runs the appropriate Gnu/Linux command.

---

As a starting point, my current attempt is:

```
echo "CPU `LC_ALL=C top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk '{print 100 - $1}'`% RAM `free -m | awk '/Mem:/ { printf("%3.1f%%", $3/$2*100) }'` HDD `df -h / | awk '/\// {print $(NF-1)}'`"
```

Note: I don't have any expected output specifically. It is enough if the output is understandable and It would be useful if the output is in a format that is easy to store in a python dictionary, e.g. `{ "CPU": "3", "RAM": "58", "HDD": 30"}`.

where these numerical values(3,58,30) are the percentage of usage of CPU, RAM and Hard disk.

Comment: mpstat, free, df.  Why do you expect to find *one* command to do three different things, efficiently?  Not to mention that “percentage of usage” is a very nuanced subject for both CPU and RAM; there is no single correct answer for either of those.

Comment: Which OS are you using? (Linux is a kernel, not an operating system)

Comment: Note: `$()` form is preferred over back-ticks. Back-ticks are much harder to quote.

Comment: @Wildcard I would expect multiple commands clubbed together like my current attempt which is being put in the question body.

Comment: @rakeshkotian got it.  Please edit your question (and its title) to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be running this on a regular basis I'd suggest you create a small script to manage the data generation. It's far more readable - and therefore maintainable.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
cpu=$(LC_ALL=C top -bn1 -p0 | awk '/^%Cpu/{print 100-$8}')
mem=$(free -m | awk '/^Mem:/{printf("%3.1f\n", $3/$2 *100)}')
dsk=$(df -h / | awk '$NF=="/"{print $(NF-1)+0}')

printf '{"CPU": "%3.1f", "RAM": "%3.1f", "HDD": "%3.1f"}\n' $cpu $mem $dsk
exit 0
```

Example

```
./546179.sh
{"CPU": "53.7", "RAM": "49.3", "HDD": "46.0"}
```

If you really are dead set on crashing this all into a single line, it's easy enough to do so but the resulting code is pretty much unreadable

Example

```
printf '{"CPU": "%3.1f", "RAM": "%3.1f", "HDD": "%3.1f"}\n' $(LC_ALL=C top -bn1 -p0|awk '/^%Cpu/{print 100-$8}') $(free -m|awk '/^Mem:/{printf("%3.1f\n",$3/$2*100)}') $(df -h /|awk '$NF=="/"{print $(NF-1)+0}')
{"CPU": "53.7", "RAM": "49.3", "HDD": "46.0"}
```